# Days between a date and a generic birthday in Pandas metaframe

Tags: pandas, dataframe

I have in a dataframe: 
Customer ID,
Customer date of birth,
date of purchase.

I need a function to calculate the distance in +/- days between the date of birth and the date of purchase

for example if date of birth is 20/12/1960 and date of purchase is 16/01/2019 I need to have 27 which is 27 days after the birthday or if the date of purchase is 05/12/2018 I need -15 which is 15 days before the birthday.

Any suggestions?

Answer (score 1):

Since you need to stay within the year of purchase, you need to extract the day of the year for the birthday and the purchase date which can be done using .dt.dayofyear as follows:

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np


df=pd.DataFrame({'customer_id':[1,2,3],
          'birthday':pd.to_datetime(['20/12/1960','2/6/1980','6/1/1972']),
         'purchase_date':pd.to_datetime(['1/1/2004','5/25/2018','3/4/2010'])})

df['days_away']=df['birthday'].dt.dayofyear - df['purchase_date'].dt.dayofyear  
df
```

Answer (score 0):

You can separate this into two. First, create a new column for the looked up birthday date. Second, subtract these two date columns to get the timedelata (and do .dt.days to get this in days).